# React Typescript - ReactNode type cuts string literals

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Suppose I have an interface with a prop that accepts string literals like this:

```js
interface IProps {
  icon?: "success" | "warning" | "error" | "info";
  ...
}
```

The icon is then picked from a dictionary. Let's say I also want to accept a custom icon, I'd add the `React.ReactNode` type to the union:

```js
interface IProps {
  icon?: "success" | "warning" | "error" | "info" | React.ReactNode;
  ...
}
```

After adding it, the type of the icon prop is cut only to React.ReactNode and I lose all the help from the editor (for example when passing an icon prop to the component).

Is there a way to type it better, so the typing also keeps the string literals?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason that that's happening is that `React.ReactNode` is a union which includes `string`. As a result any string is now legal, and so as far as the type information is concerned there's nothing special about `"success"`, `"warning"`, etc.

I do know a trick which will confuse typescript enough that it continues to give editor hints for the individual strings. Rather than creating a union with `string`, create it with `(string & {})`. Every string will match with `(string & {})`, but typescript doesn't notice that the types `"success"`, `"warning"`, etc are made obsolete by it.

For example:

```
type Example = "foo" | (string & {});
const test: Example = // when i type here, vscode gives me a hint for "foo", but any string is legal
```

So to do the same in your case, you will need to create a union that has all the stuff in `React.ReactNode`, minus `string`, and plus `(string & {})`. The following should do the trick:

```
interface IProps {
  icon?: "success" | "warning" | "error" | "info" | Exclude<React.ReactNode, string> | (string & {})
  ...
}
```